# I use DATEDIFF to subtract my time but I got 0 answer every time I execute

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, datediff

my sql statement is like this:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(hh, TimeIn,OutTime ) AS Hours_Rendered
FROM DTR_TimeRecord
```

Comment: what is date of timeln and outtime ?

Comment: Please edit your question to include sample data (preferably as DDL + DML) and desired results.

Comment: Read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx for information about how DATEDIFF works

Answer (score 0):

Please take note that DATEDIFF implicitly casts string literals as a datetime2 type. This means that DATEDIFF does not support the format YDM when the date is passed as a string. You must explicitly cast the string to a datetime or smalldatetime type to use the YDM format.

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Your TimeIn and OutTime must be of same hour. like

```
TimeIn : '2016-05-17 11:31:33.190'
OutTime: '2016-05-17 11:35:41.790'

select DATEDIFF(HH, '2016-05-17 11:31:33.190', '2016-05-17 11:35:41.790' )
```

above query will always give you 0.

But let suppose your OutTime is '2016-05-17 12:35:41.790'

Then

```
select DATEDIFF(HH, '2016-05-17 11:31:33.190', '2016-05-17 12:35:41.790' )
```

Above query will give you 1.

Comment: thanks I already figured it out , I want to display the answer in this format HH:MI:SS how can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

**This will definitely help you**

> ```
>  SELECT convert(TIME,dateadd(ms,DateDiff(ss, TimeIn, OutTime )*1000,0),114) AS Hours_Rendered
>  FROM DTR_TimeRecord
> ```